# How do I replace single character in item in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been dabbling this problem for a bit, and I am very confused. So I have this array
names = ["Fern","Alexa","Constance","Daniella","Connie","Flora","Hannah","Maddie"];

and I want to change the first letter of the first name to 'b' and then return the whole thing, without completely destroying the names for Ex: instead of "Fern", it would be "Bern"

Can someone please assist. I have tried on my own many different methods and strategies, I can't figure it out. Please assist.

Thank You

Comment: `names.map(k=>k.replace(k[0],'B'))` let me know if this is what you need?

Comment: Thank You for posting. How does it work, it looks like your using an arrow function.

Comment: In JavaScript, `strings` are array like objects, since we have to replace first character we took `[0]` position, and `map` is used to generate the new array.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```js
let names = ["Fern", "Alexa", "Constance", "Daniella", "Connie", "Flora", "Hannah", "Maddie"];

let modified = names.map(e => e.replace(e[0], 'B'))

console.log(modified);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting, but can you help me explain let modified line, is this an anonymous function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map check this out, It'll help you understand the map function and the return value

Comment: The map function loops over every element and runs the function supplied to it, here ( e => e.replace(e[0], 'B')), is equal to ( function(e){ return e.replace(e[0], 'B'); } in ES5

Answer (score 0):

Iterate with for of loops to access each item and then apply replace method.

```js
var names = ["Fern","Alexa","Constance","Daniella","Connie","Flora","Hannah","Maddie"];
var newNames = [];

for(let el of names) {
  newNames.push(el.replace(el[0], 'B'));
}

console.log(newNames);
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. Can you tell me how you did it? I see you have a for loop, but what is (el.replace(el[0], 'B')) What method is this?

Comment: for of loop iterates each element of array (for each el of names), Each element of array is a string, then apply replace method => the first word of each element (el) replace with 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map`, `slice` and template string

```js
const data = ["Fern","Alexa","Constance","Daniella","Connie","Flora","Hannah","Maddie"];

const update = (arr, char) => arr.map(str => `${char}${str.slice(1)}`);

console.log(update(data, 'B'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you only want to change the first letter of the first name without changing the original names array.

First, clone the array:
`namesClone=names.slice()`.
If you don't use `slice`, both `names` and `namesClone` with be different variable names with the same data, so change to either will effect the other.

Access first name and set it to "B" + the rest:
`namesClone[0]="B"+namesClone[0].slice(1)`.
`slice(1)` returns everything from char 1 to end, without char 0 (in your example, "F").

`names` is not changed.

Comment: Did this answer your question/helped you?
If so, please select and up-vote it - thanks!